# Having trouble making a view with 2 forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I made a django view and I am able to display my configuration the way I want to except that the answers to my attributes are not editable.  I have tried a few different ways to get this to work and am struggling to find a way to get the form to allow my answers to be changable.

**My Model**

```
    class Configuration(models.Model):
    name                = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    config_type         = models.ForeignKey('ConfigType', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    company             = models.ForeignKey('companies.Company', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    creation_date       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False, null=True)
    updated             = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    sla                 = models.ForeignKey('SLA', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    install_date        = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True)
    purchase_date       = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True)
    purchase_price      = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    warranty_exp        = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True)
    end_of_life         = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True)
    #vendor             = models.ForeignKey('companies.Company', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    manufacturer        = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    mfg_part            = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    model_number        = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    serial_number       = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    tag_number          = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    notes               = models.TextField(max_length=1024, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("configurations:configuration-update", kwargs={"id": self.id})


class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    incative        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class SLA(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class ConfigType(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    inactive        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Attribute(models.Model):
    config_type     = models.ForeignKey('ConfigType', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    number          = models.IntegerField()
    attribute       = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    input_type      = models.ForeignKey('InputType', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    required        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #answer             = models.ManyToManyField('Answer')  
    inactive        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.attribute


class InputType(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Answer(models.Model):
    configuration   = models.ForeignKey('Configuration', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    attribute       = models.ForeignKey('Attribute', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)   
    text            = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    checkbox        = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    number          = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    date            = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.configuration.name + " - Attribute #" + str(self.attribute.number)
```

**My View**

```
        def configuration_update_view(request, id=id):
    obj             = get_object_or_404(Configuration, id=id)
    config_attribs  = obj.config_type.attribute_set.all()
    config_answers  = obj.answer_set.all()      
    form            = ConfigurationForm(request.POST or None, instance=obj) 
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save() 
    context = {
        'form': form,       
        'config_answers': config_answers,
        'config_attribs': config_attribs        
    }

return render(request, "configurations/configuration_detail.html", context)
```

**My HTML**

```
<p>Configuration Detail</p>
                    <table id="configattribs">

                        {% for attribute in config_attribs %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ attribute.number }}</td>
                            <td>{{ attribute.attribute }}</td>           
                            <td>
                                {% for answer in config_answers %}
                                {% if answer.attribute == attribute %}                                   
                                    {% if attribute.input_type.name == 'Text' %}                                        
                                        {{ answer.text }}
                                    {% elif attribute.input_type.name == 'Checkbox' %}
                                        {{ answer.checkbox }}
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}                                    
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}                                                   
                    </table>
```

Here is an image of how it looks[image]

Comment: Do you want to update the object or create a new one

Comment: the "Configuration Detail" html code displays variables, to modify them you need a form

Comment: I added a form for the answers but when displaying it it only shows the last answer in all the boxes.  I am struggling with the form to get it to work like this but making the answers a form box.  I am also a new python user so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share your form.py, and also explain what you expect from your form

Comment: ``` class ConfigAttribForm(forms.ModelForm):
 class Meta:
  model = Answer
  fields = [
   'text',
   #'checkbox',      
  ]```

Comment: I added to my view `attrib_form  = ConfigAttribForm(request.POST or None, instance=answer_obj) 
 if attrib_form.is_valid():
  attrib_form.save()`

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is have a Config and pick the type from a drop down, ex: workstation, printer, router, firewall....  Each config type will have different questions (attributes) associated with it and answers for those will be filled out by the tech.  I can log into the admin and add it and it shows properly but i have been struggling for the last month on how to get it to be a sub form that can have data entered in and save it.

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple exemple, I hope it can help:

```
class Configuration(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    config_type = models.ForeignKey('ConfigType', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    # company = models.ForeignKey('companies.Company', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    sla = models.ForeignKey('SLA', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    install_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True)
    purchase_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True)
    purchase_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    warranty_exp = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True)
    end_of_life = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    mfg_part = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    model_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    tag_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.TextField(max_length=1024, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("configurations:configuration-update", kwargs={"id": self.id})


class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    incative = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class SLA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class ConfigType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    inactive = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Attribute(models.Model):
    config_type = models.ForeignKey('ConfigType', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    attribute = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    input_type = models.ForeignKey('InputType', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    required = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    inactive = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.attribute


class InputType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Answer(models.Model):
    configuration = models.ForeignKey('Configuration', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey('Attribute', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    text = models.CharField('TEXT', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    checkbox = models.BooleanField('Checkbox', blank=True, null=True)
    number = models.IntegerField('Number', blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField('Date', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.configuration.name + " - Attribute #" + str(self.attribute.number)
```

views.py:

```
def configuration_update_view(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ConfigAttribForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            context = {'id': id}
            return render(request, "stack/configuration_detail.html", context = {'id': id})
        else:
            errors = form.errors
            answer_obj = get_object_or_404(Answer, id=id)
            answer_form = ConfigAttribForm(answer_obj)
            context = {'form': answer_form, 'ERROR': errors, 'id':id}
            return render(request, "stack/configuration_detail.html", context)
    else:
        answer_obj = Answer.objects.filter(id__exact=id).values().last()
        print(answer_obj)
        answer_form = ConfigAttribForm(answer_obj)
        context = {'form': answer_form, 'id':id}
        return render(request, "stack/configuration_detail.html", context)
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="form">
    <p>Configuration Detail</p>
             <form action="{% url 'stack:configuration_update_view' id=id %}" id="myform" method="POST" >
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form }}
                 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
             </form>
</div>
<p class="erreur">{{ ERROR }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

form.py

```
class ConfigAttribForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks I'll test this and let you know

Comment: This did not help.  I guess what I am trying to accomplish is a nested form within a form.  My main form is a config form that takes generic config data and when the config type is selected it should show a nested q&a form for a particular type that is selected.  So i need to do some digging into nested forms.